# Get method specifically to handle a 0 value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In my web api controller method I have.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetMember(int id)
    {
        Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
        if (member == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }


        return Ok(member);
    }
```

Basically its checking here if there  is no current member with an id = 0, its returning NotFound ... and that is what the UI is receiving.

The scenario is that for a 0 value the API should provide a new item with good defaults.Any examples on how to achieve this?

I came up with this but not able to get it to work right.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetMember(int id)
    {
        Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
        if (id > 0)
        {
            var members = db.Members.Find();
            member = members.FirstOrDefault((m) => m.MemberId == id);
            //return NotFound();

            if (member == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
               db.Members.Add(member);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            return Ok(member);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Are you saying that if GetMember(...) is called with a id value of '0' that we should return a new default member object?  But, if the GetMember(...) method is called with something other than 0 we should try to find the corresponding member in the db.Members collection and return that?  If it's not found, then it should return "NotFound()"?

Comment: So you want the controller to create a new `member` object, and insert it as a record in the database if `member` turns out to be null? The question is all over the place, and really your attempt to achieve what it is you want provides no insight.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are exactly asking for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Found it hard to explain my problem. But Yes what you both explained is  exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize a new member object and return it to the calling method.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetMember(int id)
{
    Member member = new Member();
    if (id > 0)
    {
        var members = db.Members.Find();
        member = members.FirstOrDefault((m) => m.MemberId == id);
    }
    else
    {
        // Set some values if you need Ok(new Member { MemberId = 0, FirstName = "New"} )
    }

    return Ok(member);
}
```

Comment: _"or add to the database and get the member"_ see my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304236/get-method-specifically-to-handle-a-0-value/31304434?noredirect=1#comment50598723_31304488), you may not want to do that depending on why this method is called with id=0.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I completely agree, it would not be a good idea to add this to a database.

Comment: Not sure why the above code example is doing a find twice? Suggestion: Remove the first call to Find and instead just declare the member variable. Then only if the id > 0 is it worth doing the find passing in the Id. If the Find then finds the item, the FirstOrDefault method should not be required?

Comment: @DeborahK has a good suggestion. I used what submitter had and just made the small change, do you need me to update my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand the goal, but this might do if I understand correctly:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetMember(int id)
{
    Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
    if (member == null)
    {
        if (id != 0)
        {
            member = new Member();
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
    return Ok(member);
}
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: @CodeCaster, you could be correct. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IHttpActionResult GetMember(int id)
{
    Member member = null; 

    if(id == 0)
    {
        member = new Member();
        // Set default member values here
        // member.MemberId = 123456;
        // member.Name = "My Name";
        // set other default property values.......

        // Depending on why you are calling this method w/ a '0', you may or may not want to execute these next two lines.  It's up to you.
        db.Members.Add(member);
        db.SaveChanges();  
    }
    else
    {
        member = db.Members.Where(m => m.MemberId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    if (member == null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(member);
}
```

Comment: You don't want to save the default user immediately, that would create a new member in the database ever time a user opens the Add screen (at least I guess that's what this call is being used for). OP wants to _display_ the Add Member screen with the defaults for registration or something.

Comment: I agree with you that they may not want to save to the DB immediately, however it was happening in their original attempt, so I included it in the flow.  But, your are correct in your caution to add it immediately after creating the default value... you don't want thousands of users ending up in your database that are never actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original code that this code was based on:

```
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            Product product;
            var productRepository = new ProductRepository();

            if (id > 0)
            {
                var products = productRepository.Retrieve();
                product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == id);
                if (product == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                product = productRepository.Create();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

The requirement was to change from products to members and include EF.

Consider retaining the use of the repository and adding the EF code in the repository class instead of here. 
Also consider adding an overload to the repository retrieve method that would take in an id and locate the desired member. Then you could remove the call to FirstOrDefault here.